# Copy a table from one database to another database table

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL database named `wc_players` in which it has a table called `players_wc`. I want to copy the entire table to another database named as `fifa` which already has a table named `fifa_wc`. How can i add this new table copying from `wc_players` to `fifa` database ?

```
INSERT INTO fifa.fifa_wc
SELECT * FROM wc_players.players_wc;
```

Comment: Your example should work fine. Check your tables have the same structure, and let us know what error you're seeing if any.

Comment: *i want to copy the entire table to another database named as fifa which already has a table named fifa_wc.* Please decide does you need in: copy the whole source table replacing existing destination table or copy the source table data only into existing destination table.

Comment: You might face issues if the table structures are not exactly the same between the two databases. then you have to specify all the column names.

Comment: Your query looks good! If the table structures in both databases (`wc_players` and `fifa`) are identical, the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM ...` query you provided should work fine to copy the `players_wc` table from the `wc_players` database to the `fifa` database as the `fifa_wc` table.

Comment: Make sure that the user you're using to perform this operation has the necessary permissions in both databases to perform the `INSERT INTO` and `SELECT` operations.

Comment: It's always good practice to explicitly list column names rather than using * and hoping that the columns line up

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name
AS
SELECT 
  * 
FROM old_table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to automatize it, you can do it easily with dbeaver.

Connect to source and target database, right click on source table and select "export data". Choose database, select target table and select fields you want to export.

Next, next and wait for the data to be copied.

Here you can read all the steps with scrennshots: https://dbeaver.com/docs/dbeaver/Data-migration/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).